# How to set the target version for runnable jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a program in eclipse where inserted some libs which runs only in jre 1.6, so all my code is for `jre 1.6`. The problem is, when I export it and run it I get the same error as when I run it in `eclipse 1.7`. I just want to make the runnable jar to run in `1.6` and not use `1.7` jre.

I get this error because i want to stream a radio and mp3spi which i use is for 1.

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click in your project, select Properties, and the the "Java Compiler" section.

You can enable project specific settings or set all your projects to use jre 6.

Comment: this solves the problem when i run the program from eclipse, not when i export it.